# move background while mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousemove

I have a problem, when i reload my page, page starting at left, but I need this at center. How should i do this?
Next, when it will be in center, it should scroll to left until it 20px and so at right. Top and bottom doesnt matter.
2.JPG resolution is 2743 width, 768 height.

here is my code:

css:

```
    * {
    margin-left:-90px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    padding:-60px;
}
body {
    background:white;
}
.bg {
    background:url("2.JPG");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:768px;
    width:2743px;
    display:block;
}
```

connected^jquery 1-7 min js

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).bind('mousemove',function(e){
    $("#bg").css({ "margin-top":e.pageY/100, "margin-left":e.pageX/6 });
});
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#top').cycle({
        delay:  -1500
    });
    $('.pics img').css({
        opacity: 0.5
    });
}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#bottom').cycle({
        delay:  -3000
    });
    $('.pics img').css({
        opacity: 0.5
    });
}, 0);
});
```

this is my html:

```
<div class="bg" id="bg">&nbsp;</div>
```

Thank you very much and sorry for my English and my design knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it by onmousemove event of javascript

or you can try this for your problem i hope it will work
http://css-tricks.com/auto-moving-parallax-background/